# Compare expression with constant in CHECK constraint

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm, check-constraints

I'd like to use Django's `CheckConstraint` to add a `check` constraint to a table using PostgreSQLs `num_nonnulls()` function, similar to this:

```sql
create table foo(
    a text,
    b int,
    [...],
    check num_nonnulls(a, b, ...) = n);
```

`n` is a constant but may be different for different tables (mostly it's going to be `1` but I'd like to find a general solution). This is how far I got:

```py
class Foo(models.Model):
    a = models.TextField(null=True)
    b = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    [...]

    class Meta:
        constraints = [
            models.CheckConstraint(
                check=models.ExpressionWrapper(
                    models.Func('a', 'b', function='num_nonnulls'),
                    models.BooleanField()),
                name='num_nonnulls_check')]
```

This is of course missing the step where the result of `num_nonnulls()` is compared to some constant integer. I tried defining a function to do this:

```py
def equals(a, b):
    return models.Func(a, b, template='%(expressions[0])s = %(expressions[1])s')
```

But this doesn't work because the template argument `expressions` is (I think) a string (and `%`-template strings don't have this syntax to extract parts of an argument, I think).

Where do I go from here?

I'd like to find a solution that allows me to use arbitrary expressions supported by the Django ORM and also compare these expressions with other expressions or constants using an equality or inequality relation (e.g. `=` or `<=`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of Django 4 this is possible, see this changelog entry:

> Lookup expressions may now be used in QuerySet annotations, aggregations, and directly in filters.

This should fit your example.

```py
from django.db import models
from django.db.models.constraints import CheckConstraint
from django.db.models.expressions import Func
from django.db.models import Value
from django.db.models.fields import IntegerField, TextField


class Foo(models.Model):
    a = models.TextField(null=True)
    b = models.IntegerField(null=True)

    class Meta:
        constraints = [
            CheckConstraint(
                name='num_nonnulls_check',
                check=Exact(
                    lhs=Func('a', 'b', function='num_nonnulls', output_field=IntegerField()),
                    rhs=Value(1),
                ),
            )
        ]
```